# IndexOutOfBoundsException When read and write from Standard I/O

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm new to Java and currently doing some experiments on it.
I wrote a little program that does read and write stream of std I/O but I
kept getting exceptions thrown for out of range. Here is my code

```
int BLOCKSIZE = 128*1024;                                                                                                                                                
InputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);

OutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(System.out);



byte[] buffer = new byte[BLOCKSIZE];




int bytesRead = 0;
int writePos = 0;
int readPos = 0;
while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer,readPos,BLOCKSIZE)) != -1) {
 outStream.write(buffer,writePos,BLOCKSIZE);
 readPos += bytesRead;
 writePos += BLOCKSIZE;
 buffer = new byte[BLOCKSIZE];
}
```

Here is the exception thrown:"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:327)
        at JavaPigz.main(JavaPigz.java:73)"

73th col is the inStream.read(...) statement. Basically I want to read 128kb bytes from stdin once and write it to the stdout and go back to read another 128kb chunk, so on and so forth. The same exception is also thrown to outStream.write()

I did some debugging and it looks BufferedInputStream buffers at most 64kb chunk once. Don't know if this is true. Thank you.

Edit: I also tried doing
    InputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(System.in,BLOCKSIZE);
to specify the size of buffered chunk I want. But turns out it keeps giving size of 64kb
no matter what is specified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're increasing your `readPos` (and `writePos`) in your loop. The subsequent reads are starting at that offset for inserting into your `buffer`, and attempting to write `BLOCKSIZE` bytes into it ... which won't fit, thus giving you an index out of bounds error.

The way you have that loop written, `readPos` and `writePos` should always be `0` especially since you're creating a new buffer every time. That being said ... you really don't want to do that, you want to re-use the buffer. It looks like you're just trying to read from the input stream and write it to the output stream ...

```
while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer,readPos,BLOCKSIZE)) != -1) {
    outStream.write(buffer,writePos,bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: And similar reasoning goes for the write.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of bytes that BufferedInputStream could buffer from Stdin once a time? I did inStream.available() in the while loop and it gives me 65536 each time (except the last one). Thank you.

Comment: This is going to depend on the underlying OS and the source of the data (File, Socket, etc). More than likely you're seeing the underlying native code chunking at 64k. Honestly, when you're dealing with reading/writing large chunks like that you really should just be reading/writing from the streams directly. The buffered wrapper classes are for optimizing small read/writes (<= ~ 8k).

Answer (score 0):

your readPos and writePos correspond to the array ... not to the stream ...

set them 0 and leave them at 0

in your write call set param 3 to bytesRead instead of BLOCKSIZE